# Android studio 2.2 running very slow in windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, ram

In my windows 10 android studio 2.2 running very slow it consume 2GB Of RAM.In my project setting i did offline gradle  and compiler setting but still facing this issue.

Comment: Same for me. While compiling I can hardly browse on internet

Comment: @fillobotto is there any solution for that?

Comment: Could not find one, so I follow this post

Comment: @TimCastelijns In android studio 2.2 there is a no VM options available.

Comment: @fillobotto   Got To HELP-->EDIT CUSTOM VM OPTIONS                                copy this and save that                                                                                     -Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops